# How to solve this ordinary differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve the following O.D.E.s? I find it in a published paper, but the author doesn't mention how to solve it.

$$\frac{dq}{dt}=-y$$

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=-\frac{2xy}{q}$$

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=-\frac{y^2}{q}+\frac{2x}{q}$$

with initial conditions $q(0)=1/2,x(0)=1,\quad \text and \quad y(0)=0.$

I know the solutions are $q(t)=\frac{e^{-4t^2}}{2},x(t)=e^{-8t^2}\quad \text and \quad y(t)=4te^{-4t^2}.$ But I have no idea how it comes.

Comment: For the first ODE. What is $y$?

Comment: @Rumplestillskin The 3 unknowns about $t$ are $q,x,y$ and they have relation between each other.

Comment: The general solution is $$q(t)=au(t)\quad x(t)=ca^2u(t)^2\quad y(t)=-a(b-2ct)u(t)$$ with $$u(t)=\exp(bt-ct^2)$$ The initial conditions yield $b=0$, $a=\frac12$ and $c=4$, hence your solution is correct. To show the general solution, start with the remark that $$\frac{x'}x=2\frac{q'}q$$ hence $$x(t)=cq(t)^2$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A method consists in eliminating $t$ in order to find the relationships between $x,y$ and $q$. Then express $\frac{dq}{dt}$ as a function of $q$ only. Integration this last ODE leads to $q(t)$. Bringing it back into the equations of $x(q)$ and $y(q)$ leads to the expected result.

[image]